# Flatten only non empty cells refrence range once

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, flatten

I have two columns `A2:B` with empty and non empty cells, I want to achive a similar result to the formula in `D2` but **refrence the range `A2:B` once in the formula.** `=Formula(Range)`

```
=FILTER(FLATTEN(A2:B),FLATTEN(A2:B)<>"")
```

[**Make a copy**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hUYFW9nsEh-8a9P_xaNHlfqUlkpUmJmhi748bj8t0YA/copy) of the example.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATED!
this is now much simpler with `=TOCOL(A2:B,TRUE)`

**Use**

```
=QUERY(FLATTEN(A2:B), " where Col1 is not null ",0)
```

[image]